# React Js Data Handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how are you? I come here to ask for your help. I'm with React JS, I have these states that are requested to send them by post to generate a user.-

```js
class NuevoUsuario extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            usuario: '',
            password: '',
            persona: {
                apellido:'',
                apellidoCasada:'',
                nombre:'',
                dni:'',
                telefono:'',
                celular:'',
                email:'',
                ubicacion: {
                    direccion:'',
                    ciudad:'',
                    provincia:'',
                    codigoPostal:'',
                    paisId: 0,
                }

            }
            
        }
        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
        
    }

    handleInput(e){
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value })
        console.log(this.state);
    }
```

Now what I want is that from

```js
 <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="exampleInput">Apellido</label>
                    <input
                      className="form-control input-lg"
                      type="text"
                      name="apellido"                                     
                      onChange={this.handleInput}                      
                    />
                  </div>
```

when doing that, the username and password are assigned, but the last name and all the others are not assigned to person.lastname or person.name, a new state is added as well, and those of person are empty {}

[image]

What I want is to be kept in person.surname. If you can help me I will be very grateful

Comment: Avoid code screenshot please

Comment: What do want to set. Still confuse about what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `input` tag has attribute `name` that you use to select which property in `state` to update

```
<input
    className="form-control input-lg"
    type="text"
    name="apellido"                                     
    onChange={this.handleInput}                      
/>
```

And `handleInput` use `e.target.name` to specify which property to update

```
handleInput(e){
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

`e.target.name` will be equal to `apellido`, so `this.state.apellido` will be equal to input value.

Setting `name=persona.apellido` will not solve you task. You'll not be able to access `this.state.persona.apellido`.

1. The easiest solutuion I see is to make `state` one plane object without nested obects. Like so

   ```
   this.state = {
       usuario: '',
       password: '',
       apellido:'',
       apellidoCasada:'',
       nombre:'',
       dni:'',
       // And so on
   }
   ```
2. Another solution is to parse `this.target.name` in `handleInput` like so (not tested!)

   ```
   handleInput(e){
       let name = e.target.name.split('.');
       switch (name.length)
           case 1:
               this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value });
               break;
           case 2:
               this.setState({[name[0]]: {...this.state[name[0]], [name[1]]: e.target.value }});
               break;
           case 3:
               this.setState({[name[0]]: {...this.state[name[0]], [name[1]]: { ...this.state[name[0]][name[1]], [name[2]]: e.target.value }}});
               break;
           default:;
       }
       console.log(this.state);
   }
   ```

But I not reccomend second solution as it overcomplicated and harder to maintain in future.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in React, you need a 2-way binding between your state and input fields. You do that by adding a value prop to your input like below:

```
<input
    className="form-control input-lg"
    type="text"
    name="apellido"   
    value={ this.state.persona.apellido }     <----- Two Way                            
    onChange={this.handlePersonaInput}        <----- Binding              
/>
```

Second, your username and password fields work because your handleInput method can only find their values in the state's first level of depth. Your Persona variables are in the second level of the state depth, and your address info is in the third level of depth. In order to reach Persona values, you need to setup a second input handler:

```
    handlePersonaInput(e){
        this.setState({persona[e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }
```

and your persona address fields will have third input handler:

```
    handleAddressInput(e){
        this.setState({persona.ubicacion[e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }
```

If you're not satisfied with 3 input handlers in your component, you can merge them into one like below:

```
    handleInput(e){
        const { name, value } = e.target;

        if (name === 'usuario' || name === 'password')
           this.setState({[name]: value });

        else if (name === 'apellido' || name === 'apellidoCasada' || etc..)
           this.setState({persona[name]: value });

        else if (name === 'direccion' || etc..)
           this.setState({persona.ubicacion[name]: value });
    }
```

Just remember to think about your state structure when you want to modify one of its variables.